# How to extract good JSON from corrupted string data using Scala?

Tags: regex, scala

I need to parse out valid JSON string from within a corrupted string.

I have the following data coming in:

> val data: String ="[|улUў├m(ЇOfЄ)”{"price":"999.99","prodno":"123456"},|улUў├m(ЇOfЄ)”{"price":"999.99","prodno":"123456"}(ЇOfЄ)”]"

I need to match with this:

`val match_patt = """\{(?:[^{}]|())*\}""".r`

When I try this:

`var good_data = match_patt.findAllIn(data)`

I get these errors:

> error: illegal character '\u201d'

> error: ';' expected but ',' found.

I tried setting `data` to `Any` then call `toString()`, but no go.

Those bad chars could be any bad chars not those specific ones.

How can I convert `data` into an acceptable string (or something) so I can parse out the good bits.

Thanks

Comment: This works just fine: `val data: String =""""[|улUў├m(ЇOfЄ)”{"price":"999.99","prodno":"123456"},|улUў├m(ЇOfЄ)”{"price":"999.99","prodno":"123456"}(ЇOfЄ)”]""""; val pat = """\{([^{}]*)\}""".r; pat.findAllIn(data).foreach(println)`. Your broken data is obviously not valid Scala code, so you should at least enclose it in triple double quotes. Also, your regex pattern seems a bit weird and inefficient (what's the `|()` for?). Once these issues are fixed, it basically seems to work just fine.

Comment: I'm in Spark with Scala, that's how spark gives me the string. As for the regex I had (\R) in the empty parenthesis, forgot to remove the rest, seems it's not needed.                          So looks like I just need to triple quote the data coming in.